# pcap.net communicator buffers packets while thread is stopped

Tags: c#, capture, packets, pcap.net, communicator

I am using pcap.net to capture packets.
The method that captures packets is running in a new thread.
When I want to stop/resume the capture I use the ManualResetEvent to stop/resume the thread.

it works fine, the problem is when I break the capture and start it again (stop and resume the thread)  - the communicator received packets that came during the time the thread was stopped. 
I think its because of the buffer of the communicator.

is want the communicator to **not get packets** while the thread is stopped, and will **get packets again** when the thread is resumed.
any help?

My Code:

```
    #region Members
    private PacketCommunicator _Communicator;
    private IList<LivePacketDevice> _allDevices;
    private PacketDevice selectedDevice;
    private Thread captureThread;
    private ManualResetEvent _pauseEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public PacketGateway()
    {
        try
        {
            _allDevices = LivePacketDevice.AllLocalMachine;
            selectedDevice = _allDevices[0];
            captureThread = new Thread(StartListening);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;

        }
    }

    // Starts/Resumes the Thread
    public void Start()
    {
     /// Starts the Thread the first time
        if (captureThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Unstarted)
        {
            _Communicator = selectedDevice.Open();
            captureThread.Start();
        }
     /// Resumes the Thread
        if (captureThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)
        {
            _pauseEvent.Set();
        }
    }


    public void Stop()
    {
        /// stop the thread
        _pauseEvent.Reset();
    }


// Starts to recieve packets
    public void StartListening()
    {
        try
        {
            _Communicator.ReceivePackets(0, HandlePacket);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }


 // Handles Packet
    private void HandlePacket(Packet packet)
    {
        // some work..
    }

    #endregion
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping/Starting the thread is just the wrong way to do this. Have the thread run all the time, tell it when you want to stop/start capturing, and have it throw away/process the packets depending on that.